# How to replace all white spaces in file names in GCP Cloud Storage?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, sed, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a bucket on GCP cloud storage and I want to rename all files that have a white space in their filename to the name where the whitespace is removed by a hyphen (-).

I tried something like

```
gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/ | sed 's/ /-/g/gsutil mv & \1/'
```

Unfortunately, I cant get the sed command work to replace the whitespace and then use the gsutil mv command to actually rename the file.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to rename files into Cloud Storage?

Comment: It would help if you could show some sample output of `gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/`. Does it preserve `gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/` inside the returned filenames?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yes, `gsutil` returns the entire object name (including parent path).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to replace any space with `-` in some file names that you get with `gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/`, you can use

```sh
gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/ | \
  while read f; do
    gsutil -m mv "$f" "${f// /-}";
  done;
```

[`gsutil mv` command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv) moves/renames files, and `${f// /-}` is a variable expansion syntax where each space is replaced with `-` (the `//` stands for *all occurrences*). Thus, you do not need `sed` here.

Comment: Once small change request. `gsutil` is listing files in Cloud Storage. Your move statement is moving files on local storage.

Comment: I think so. I plan to try your example this weekend. Your renaming expression is very cool. I use `sed` and `regex` a lot and this goes on my expert's list.

Comment: The problem i have:
If I execute the command `$(gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/)` just like that (in the terminal directly or in a sh file) it returns as @John Hanley described the whole object name with the parent path. 
e.g.
 gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/file1.txt
 gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/file 2.txt
Even if there is a white space it is one object.

SEE NEXT COMMENT

Comment: BUT: If I use this command in the for loop as mentioned on your answer, the objects will be split at the white spaces. Then the outout is:

    `gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/file1.txt
    gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/file
    2.txt`

--> Three objects

Comment: @nikos Sorry, I forgot to quote the `ls` command.

Comment: In this case, there is only ONE cycle of the for loop. The variable f would be `gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/file1.txt  gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/file 2.txt`. The entries are all in one line, separated by blanks.

Comment: @nikos Maybe you do not need the `ls` command at all? Try `for f in gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/*.*; do` ...

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, no, then it won't iterate through the files and just return 'gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/*.*' statement.

Comment: Try `while read -r f; do gsutil -m mv "$f" "${f// /-}"; done < <(gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/)`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thank you very much for the support! Its working like that:
`gsutil ls gs://<bucket>/<folder_with_the_files_to_rename>/ | while read f; do
  gsutil -m mv "$f" "${f// /-}";
done;`